# SATA controller on Artix 7

Tags: fpga, vivado, sata

**Problem background:** My ultimate aim is to implement a SATA host controller on an Artix 7 FPGA. Having said that I am first focusing on the physical layer. Through my research I have found and read through open source IP located here: http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/tessier/rcg/virtex4-sata/sata_core.html

The IP described above is for an older family of FPGA devices and hence cannot be easily imported into the newer Vivado environment.

**My question:** Would it be better to start the physical layer from scratch using the 7-series transceiver wizard OR should I try to migrate bit by bit the old protocol to be used on the newer device?

**Important notes:**

- Rocket IO transceivers are not supported in Vivado
- The new device does not have a SATA output port itself like the ML405 board used for the open source core
- From the product guide it seems like the 7-series transceiver wizard handles all the SATA physical layer things such as OOB, 8b/10b, comma detection etc. BUT there is no formal documentation or example design I can locate about SATA.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a SATA controller for a Spartan 6 and Virtex 6. It was not easy and it needs some work to be usable.

That said, I would suggest using Coregen to implement the Physical layer.

I found that there are quite a few registers that are not documented within the gigabit transceivers of the different FPGA generations. It's much better to follow the wizard. If I were going to start out on an Artix7 I would select the following:

**Line Rate/RefClk Selection**
[image]

**Encoding and Clocking**
[image]

**Comma Alignment and Equalization**
[image]

**PCIe, SATA, PRBS**
[image]

**CB and CC Sequence**
[image]

Most of the selections are the default SATA 2 configurations but I chose to use 32-bit data bus.

**Side note**

Although you didn't ask I think this should be said:

While developing I wrote a simulated phy layer. It worked out really well because it both sped up development and I could disable the scrambler whenever I needed to.

Creating a simulated phy layer shouldn't be that bad. It really boils down to something like this interface:

```
module sata_phy_layer (

input               rst,            //reset
input               clk,

input               platform_ready,   //the underlying physical platform is
output              platform_error,
output              linkup,           //link is finished

output  [31:0]      tx_dout,
output              tx_is_k,
output              tx_comm_reset,
output              tx_comm_wake,
output              tx_elec_idle,
input               tx_oob_complete,

input   [31:0]      rx_din,
input   [3:0]       rx_is_k,  //I should have kept the rx/tx_is_k consistent 4 or 1 :/
input               rx_elec_idle,
input               rx_byte_is_aligned,

input               comm_init_detect,
input               comm_wake_detect,

output              phy_ready,
input               phy_error,
output      [3:0]   lax_state
);
```

I'm not here to support my old sata work, in fact I discourage it. There were some parts of it that I got working in a, shall I say... inelegant way.. but it might help if you are looking for a place to start.

[SATA Project in Verilog](https://github.com/CospanDesign/nysa-sata)